# Jquery replace html with another html

Tags: jquery, html, replace

I have this html on my document

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="">
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
</iframe>
```

And i need to replace with another custom html code I want
for example with this:

```
<div class="customdiv">any content I want</div>
```

any idea?
the problem is that i cant target the element iframe because in the same page I can have many iframe but with different code, I only need to target the ones that have the specific code from up
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use the [`replaceWidth`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) function and **not** the `html` function the other posts are suggesting, as this will recreate entirely new elements. In it's most simple form it's as follows:

```
$('div.second').replaceWith('<h2>New heading</h2>');
```

But you can also pass an element reference or jquery object to it.

```
$('iframe').replaceWith($(".customdiv"));
```

In general though this is not advisable and rather you should add or show/hide the element and `remove` the other element by hand (`.remove()`).

You point out in your comment that you wish only to match empty iframes. This is going to be *far* harder to do, as I fear that your iframe is going to be on another domain (that's normally the case with iframes) so you can't access anything that's inside the iframe tag to put it that way. If on the other hand the iframe is on your own domain you should reconsider the use of iframes, though in that case you can use the `contains` jquery function checking for the existance of a node that's not present in the empty documents (or `find` the body element and check it's empty)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('iframe').html( $('.customdiv').html() );
```

use `.html` method to get or set the innerhtml for a element.

Comment: the problem is, that i can have many iframe on the same page, so i only need to replace only the ones that have this:
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="">
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
</iframe>

not all the iframes

Comment: @canute the HTML property can be read, too, so loop over the iframes using jQuery's **each** and replace those.

Answer (score 0):

This will replace the contents of the `customdiv` element using JQuery [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method.

```
$('.customdiv').html('your html string');
```